# Как можно сделать метод быстрее?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, jni

Я новичок в c++

Есть вот такой метод

```
void FrameManager::LoadFrameData(char const *filename, const uint i_subIndex) {
std::array<float, 3> IGNORE{};

high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

util::ReadFileMTR(i_subIndex, filename, IGNORE, m_vertices, m_textures, m_indices);

high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
long long int duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "LOAD FRAME INTERNAL METHOD", "LOAD FRAME INTERNAL METHOD ::: %s", std::to_string(duration).c_str());

std::vector<GLfloat> newVert;
newVert.resize(m_indices.size() * 3);
int count = 0;

for (unsigned int index : m_indices) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
        newVert[count] = m_vertices[index * 3 + k];
        count++;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < m_indices.size(); i++) {
    m_indices[i] = static_cast<unsigned int>(i);
}

m_vertices = newVert;
}
```

Как можно сделать метод еще быстрее?

Я имею ввиду, что мне не нравятся эти 2 цикла внизу... Как из можно заменить, чтоб ускорить это

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш первый цикл (двойной) использует диапазонную (range) версию с итерируемой переменной по значению. Т.е. даже изменяя `index`, вы не измените значения внутри массива `m_indices`:

```
for (unsigned int index : m_indices) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
        newVert[count] = m_vertices[index * 3 + k];
        count++;
    }
}
```

Во втором же вы как раз меняете значения в этом массиве:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_indices.size(); i++) {
    m_indices[i] = static_cast<unsigned int>(i);
}
```

Т.к. обработка идёт вполне себе линейно (нет каких-либо перескоков), то эти циклы вполне себе можно объединить в один. Учитывая, что (во втором случае) нужен именно индекс элемента массива, общий цикл лучше сделать как раз на базе второго.

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_indices.size(); i++) {
    auto& index = m_indices[i];
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
        newVert[count++] = m_vertices[index * 3 + k];
    }
    index = static_cast<unsigned int>(i);
}
```

Ещё можно попробовать вариант разворачивания внутреннего цикла, хотя, оптимизатор может и сам что-то подобное сделать, я думаю.

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_indices.size(); i++) {
    auto& index = m_indices[i];

    newVert[count++] = m_vertices[index * 3 + 0];
    newVert[count++] = m_vertices[index * 3 + 1];
    newVert[count++] = m_vertices[index * 3 + 2];

    index = static_cast<unsigned int>(i);
}
```

Comment: Я слышал, что можно в c++ копировать память вроде `memcopy` или что то такое, что думаете насчет этого подхода?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko любой подход нужно измерять, не стоит полагаться на преждевременную оптимизацию, она может наоборот всё испортить. В первую очередь установите подходящие ключи оптимизации компилятора и уже после этого пробуйте ручные способы изменения алгоритма, если результат окажется неудовлетворительным.